# Rocketchip TileLink increase burst transfer size

Tags: chisel, rocket-chip

I'd like to **transfer 2048 bytes** in a single Get/Put burst in the RocketChip TileLink node.

I do the following:

```
val a_size = 6 // max 64 bytes

val put = edge.Put(wsource, waddr, a_size, a_data)._2 
val get = edge.Get(rsource, raddr, a_size)._2
```

If I increase a_size to 8 or 10, I get the following error:

**'A' channel carries Get type unsupported by manager**

How do I fix this issue?